# CMake incorrectly identifying valid C++ compiler options?

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules, cmake-language

I have a set of C++ potential compiler flags stored in a variable and over it, I'm running the following test on CMake **3.14.5**, to see which ones applies and which doesn't to a certain version of the compiler (I'm using **GCC**, **CLANG** and **ICC** to compile the same project, hence the necessity to apply to each only the relevant flags):

```
foreach (FLAG IN LISTS CXX_COMPILER_FLAGS_TO_USE)
    # Check if the compiler supports the flag.
    string(REGEX REPLACE "[-=+]" "" FLAG_NO_SIGNS ${FLAG}) # <- The variable recieving the result of the test can't have those signs in its name
    check_cxx_compiler_flag(${FLAG} CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_${FLAG_NO_SIGNS})
    if(CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_${FLAG_NO_SIGNS})
        message(STATUS "Flag ${FLAG} accepted by C++ compiler")
        string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " ${FLAG}")
    else()
        message(STATUS "Flag ${FLAG} not accepted by C++ compiler")
    endif()
endforeach()
```

For GCC 8 and the `-Wabi` flag, I get:

```
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_Wabi
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_Wabi - Failed
-- Flag -Wabi not accepted by C++ compiler
```

Now, if instead of pushing the flags inside **`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`**, I use **`add_compile_options()`**, the result of my test changes!!!:

```
foreach (FLAG IN LISTS CXX_COMPILER_FLAGS_TO_USE)
    # Check if the compiler supports the flag.
    string(REGEX REPLACE "[-=+]" "" FLAG_NO_SIGNS ${FLAG})
    check_cxx_compiler_flag(${FLAG} CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_${FLAG_NO_SIGNS})
    if(CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_${FLAG_NO_SIGNS})
        message(STATUS "Flag ${FLAG} accepted by C++ compiler")
        add_compile_options($<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${FLAG}>)  # <- ONLY THIS LINE CHANGED
    else()
        message(STATUS "Flag ${FLAG} not accepted by C++ compiler")
    endif()
endforeach()
```

The test for `-Wabi` now reports:

```
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_Wabi
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_Wabi - Success
-- Flag -Wabi accepted by C++ compiler
```

Which leads the second case to fail on compile time later:

```
cc1plus: error: -Wabi won't warn about anything [-Werror=abi]
```

It's like **`add_compile_options()`** would have modified the result of **`check_cxx_compiler_flag()`**, which is weird since the latter runs *BEFORE* the former.

Just out of curiosity, I combined both approaches in the same test (which could sound redundant):

```
add_compile_options($<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${FLAG}>)
string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " ${FLAG}")
```

and that works, meaning `-Wabi` is NOT added to the compilation options for C++ files.

I wouldn't expect that replacing the usage of **`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`** by **`add_compile_options()`** would change the result of a test made *PREVIOUSLY* and using a third function.

So, the question is: **Am I doing something I'm not supposed to? Or did I hit a real bug?**

I couldn't find anything similar in the knowledge base, and when I post the issue to the [CMake bug tracker](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19441), I really didn't understand the response.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It looks like the variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is changed between the different `cmake` runs. This is why you got different results of the check. You may add `message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")` before `check_cxx_compiler_flag` invocation to see a difference.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I think you misunderstood my question. I'm using exactly the same script in two different runs, modifying only one line on it between the runs. It's not the same code with the small change repeated twice in the same script.

Comment: I understand that. But it is almost impossible that calls after `check_cxx_compiler_flag` affect on its results. So I guess that results of that call are affected by something else, e.g. by different value of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` which you have at the time of that check.

Comment: That's what really puzzles. I'm only changing the line I mentioned, which is run _AFTER_ `check_cxx_compiler_flag`, I can't figure out how that line could affect the result of an operation run previously.

Comment: So, have you tried to print value of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable before the `check_cxx_compiler_flag`? Exactly this variable may affect on the check result.

Comment: Sorry for the so late response :-).
Yes, I printed the variable, as:
`message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")` before
`check_cxx_compiler_flag(${FLAG}` 
and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` simply remains empty all the time.